Filter out non-empty text in elasticsearch
How to do that without regex?
Lets say I have a this doc in ES:
{
  myField:""
}

MyField is text type (no keyword)
I have tried these:
"exists": {
  "field": "myField",
}


"must_not":{
  "term": {
    "myField": {
      "value": "",
    }
  }
}

But both returned the empty field.
The only solution which works for me is regex:
"must":{
  "regexp": {
    "myField": {
      "value": ".*",
    }
  }
}

But regex usage can be performance heavy
Is there any solution to filter out non-empty text fields easily (without changing the mappings)?

You can try using range query and search values greater than empty string
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "myField": {
        "gt": ""
      }
    }
  }
}

